# SQL Cursor FOR Loop w/ variables in schema name

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql, cursor

Very new to ORACLE SQL and just discovered Cursor FOR LOOP. Having trouble to get this basic loop working. I basically want to retrive some values per row iteration from a table using a cursor loop. I will use these retrieved values to create tables and execute other simple statements.

2 problems:

1) I get an error "PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: ;" Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

2) How do I use the column values per row iteration as a variable, so I can use them as part of the table name I am trying to create?

My code is the following:

```
declare
cursor c1 is
select *
from table;

begin

for row in c1 loop

create table table.$row.column <---Wrong syntax I know. I don't know how to put this in a variable

end loop;
end;
```

EDIT: This is the actual code I am running to make it work:

```
--/
begin

for a_group in (select groupid
from ent_merged_20141007.group_metadata)

loop

execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE' || a_group.groupid || 'REST OF STATEMENT HERE';

end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: If you wanted to create a table dynamically, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.  It is, however, extremely unusual in Oracle to create objects at runtime.  And it would be extremely unusual for someone that is just learning about a for loop to be assigned a task that would really benefit from dynamic SQL.  That combination raises all sorts of red flags to me.  Can you take a step back and explain the business problem you are trying to solve and why you think that dynamically creating tables in a loop is the proper technical solution?

Comment: so when it comes to normal queries and such I am completely fine. However this is my first attempt at 1) using loops in SQL, 2) using variables. It is certainly not my first time using a for loop or variables in general. I come from a Java and web programming background, and this would have been my thought to do in those languages.

Comment: The business problem is just to generate x # of tables based on row entries in an existing table in one sql script. although now that you've mentioned how unusual it is to do in SQL, i might do it in another language

Comment: The language is immaterial (and, incidentally, you're using PL/SQL here, not SQL)-- the problem is that dynamically creating objects in Oracle is generally frowned upon regardless of the language you're using.  What purpose does creating a large number of tables based on data in a different table serve?

Comment: The existing table isn't that large, maybe max 15-20 rows. It wouldn't create a large number of tables. Usually what would happen is I'd be interested in generating a table and populating it in a certain way for a certain client. That information is stored in the existing table in one row. However, if I wanted to do it for another client, I'd have to look at another row and run the same script but using information at that other row. Very tedious, so I'd rather just run them all at once in a single script using loop. is this possible?

Comment: I assume you've changed the code you're using now that you're getting a new error.  Can you edit your question to include your actual code?  I believe my examples show how to use the data from the table as the name of the table you're creating (in my examples, I assume there is a column named `table_name` in the table since you haven't told us what your table looks like) .

Comment: see new editted code

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement is missing the rest of the DDL-- you'd either want to define a set of columns or build a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement.  That's not going to create the error you're showing, however, it'll show up once we fix that error.  What tool are you using to run your PL/SQL block?  Depending on the front-end, you may be missing a `/` at the end or your front-end may be running more (or less) code than you expect.

Comment: I am using DB Visualizer. I think I got it though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you can do something like this (I'm using an implicit cursor loop rather than an explicit cursor loop just for code brevity and out of personal preference-- you can do exactly the same thing with an explicit cursor).

```
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name
              FROM some_table)
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE ' || t.table_name || ' <<add the rest of your DDL>>';
  END LOOP;
END;
```

You can build the DDL statement in a `VARCHAR2` variable and execute that as well

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name
              FROM some_table)
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'CREATE TABLE ' || t.table_name || '  <<add the rest of your DDL>>';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

That said, dynamically creating objects is generally frowned upon in Oracle.  You really want the set of objects in your schema to be fixed at the point in time that your application is installed.  A table with metadata that tells your application to dynamically build other tables is generally an architecture that is frowned upon.  If you are building different tables for different clients, I'd strongly recommend building a single table with a `client_id` column (possibly with an appropriate VPD policy) or at least creating separate schemas for each client.

Comment: tried the first method and this was the error message I got: any  clues as to why?

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
   member submultiset